# Adding elements to ArrayList using builder pattern in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, arraylist

I am trying to add elements to `ArrayList<Movements>movement` as part of a builder pattern.

The Movement class contains an `int movementId` and a `String movementName` and I would like the user to add these to the composition using the builder pattern.

I am struggling with the implementation, see below:

```java
public static class CompositionBuilder {
    private final String compositionId;
    private List<Movements> movement = new ArrayList<Movements>();
    private final String compositionName;
    private final String composerName;

    public CompositionBuilder(String compositionId,
                              String compositionName,
                              String composerName) {
        this.compositionId = compositionId;
        this.compositionName = compositionName;
        this.composerName = composerName;
    }

    //this part is where I am struggling.
    //I don't know how to populate the ArrayList
    public CompositionBuilder movement(Movements... movement) {
        for (Movements i : movement) {
            this.movement.add(i);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public Composition build() {
        return new Composition(this);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to build the composition using

```java
public class CompositionBuilderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Composition composition1 = new Composition
                .CompositionBuilder("1", "CompositionOne", "John Doe")
                .movement()//enter movement values here
                .build();
        System.out.println(composition1);
    }
}
```

Composition Constructor:

```java
private Composition(CompositionBuilder builder) {
    this.compositionId = builder.compositionId;
    this.movement = builder.movement;
    this.compositionName = builder.compositionName;
    this.composerName = builder.composerName;
}
```

Comment: What problem do you see with your implementation?

Comment: In `CompositionBuilderTest` I want to enter `movement(movementId, movementName)`. This doesn't work. I also don't think a variable length argumant is correct in `CompositionBuilder movement` but I can't figure out the alternative.

Comment: @macattack You would need to call the `Movements` constructor: `movement(new Movements(movementId, movementName))`

Comment: @Alexis C. I am getting a blank element in the ArrayList, it just prints Movement: []

Comment: @macattack Could you show the `Composition` constructor please?

Comment: @Alexis C. See above

Comment: @macattack I did exactly the same thing and it worked. The error is somewhere else (maybe the way you are printing the content?)

Comment: @Alexis C. Ok thanks, I'll keep working on it. I'm tackling some new concepts here but I'm sure I can figure it out.

Comment: I figured it out, I forgot to override the toString method in the Movements class.

Answer (score 3):

Using the CompositionBuilder to create instances of Movement would go against SRP (and you would need to modify the signature of the `movement` method in the builder). Rather, you should pass instances of Movement into the `movement(Movement...movements)` method, calling either a constructor or a factory

```java
Composition composition1 = new Composition
      .CompositionBuilder("1", "CompositionOne", "John Doe")
      .movement(Movement.newInstance(id, name), Movement.newInstance(id2, name2))
      .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't found a satisfied existing util from 3-part lib to implement this. So I wrote an util, here is the usage:

```java
List<Integer> list = CollectionBuilder.fromCollection(new ArrayList<Integer>())
                .addVarargs(1, 2, 3)
                .add(4)
                .build();

assertThat(list, is(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4)));
```

```java
public class CollectionBuilder<C extends Collection<T>, T> {

    private C coll;

    public CollectionBuilder(C coll) {
        this.coll = coll;
    }

    public static  <C extends Collection<T>, T> CollectionBuilder<C, T>  from(Supplier<C> collSupplier, T... t) {
        return new CollectionBuilder<>(collSupplier.get()).addVarargs(t);
    }

    public static <C extends Collection<T>, T> CollectionBuilder<C, T> fromCollection(C coll) {
        return new CollectionBuilder<>(coll);
    }

    public static <C extends Collection<T>, T> CollectionBuilder<C, T> from(Supplier<C> collSupplier) {
        return new CollectionBuilder<>(collSupplier.get());
    }

    public CollectionBuilder<C, T> add(T ele) {
        coll.add(ele);
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionBuilder<C, T> addVarargs(T... e) {
        Collection<T> ts = Arrays.asList(e);
        this.coll.addAll(ts);
        return this;
    }

    public CollectionBuilder<C, T> addAll(Collection<T> c) {
        this.coll.addAll(c);
        return this;
    }

    public C build() {
        return coll;
    }

}
```